# Commenting on revisions/edits

Tags: discussion

How do we handle discussion around edits? Specifically, I disagree with the title revision to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/23155/revisions) -- I don't think the new title appropriately encompasses the question. How do I share feedback? Just add a comment to the question, even though it's specifically about the latest edit?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a comment, or you can just change the edit to what you see fit.  If it starts going back and forth, we can address it then.  Most of the time, nobody's feelings are gonna get hurt and it ends after the next edit.

Comment: I'm for just-do-it. It's an iterative process of improvement.

Comment: Rfusca has pretty much nailed it on the head.

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work. :)